# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k \ln(k)^2}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Does $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k \ln(k)^2}$$ converge over $\Bbb R$, and if so, towards which limit?

Comment: If it is $k(\ln(k))^2$, yes. If it is $k\ln(k^2)$, no.

Comment: Do you maybe want to start the summation at $k=2$?

Comment: @WillO Actually, I do. That's just an embarassing typo

Comment: @AndréNicolas there is no usual syntactic convention that would allow for it to be intepreted as $k \ln(k^2)$

Comment: There is no convention in mathematics that would allow the other interpretation either. Computer languages are another story.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the theorem that if $a_n$ is decreasing and positive then 
$\sum a_{n}$ converges iff $\sum 2^na_{2^n} $ converges.
In this case we get,
 $$\sum \frac{1}{n^2 \ln 2}$$ which converges.
No idea what the sum is.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. I forgot about Cauchy's condensation test for a moment.

Answer (score 2):

For partial summation you have $$\underset{k=2}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\frac{1}{k\,\log\left(k\right)^{2}}=\left(H_{n}-1\right)\log\left(n\right)^{-2}+2\int_{2}^{n}\frac{\left(H_{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }-1\right)dt}{t\,\log\left(t\right)^{3}}\,\,\,\,(1)$$
 where $H_{n}$
  is the n-th armonic number and $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor$ 
  is the floor function. Using the inequality $$H_{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }<\log\left(t\right)+1$$
 you have the upper bound $$(1)<\left(H_{n}-1\right)\log\left(n\right)^{-2}+2\int_{2}^{n}\frac{dt}{t\,\log\left(t\right)^{2}}=\left(H_{n}-1\right)\log\left(n\right)^{-2}+\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}-\frac{2}{\log\left(n\right)}\overrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}.$$